# How to open a GNOME 3 window from console?

Tags: fedora, gnome

in my GNOME 2 ubuntu i used to issue this command to open a new window to browse the files in some folder:

```
nautilus ./
```

For example, i could go to a difficult location through the console, and when i found it I opened the window:

```
cd /home/santiago/Music/Blues/BB-King/Live/Live at...
nautilus ./
```

And that folder was displayed in the window, and i could browse it regulary.

But now I have GNOME 3 on Fedora 15 and that doesn't work any more.

I think it's becouse the process doesn't return control to the console, so if i want to do that different times, the subsequents calls to `nautilus ./` open the first location.

Thank you!

Comment: It is not a random window you want to open, it is nautilus. (You won't have any issues if use used xterm).

Comment: Uhm, that makes sense. I didn't get the xterm part...

Comment: Sorry for the typo: I mean "no issues if you used xterm". The point is that nautilus is a GTK3 application which probably do some GtkApplication (session related) things that other GTK or X11 applications don't.

Comment: have you tried just the `nautilus .` (without the slash)?

Answer (score 2):

It is not so much GNOME 2/3 but the difference in process handling. Previously Nautilus handled desktop (i.e. folders and background). However in Gnome 3 it is no longer handled by it and hence the Nautilus is not running.

For various reasons the first call opens the program while others simply sends IPC signals to it. There was known bug that Nautilus interpreted calls with respect to its current working directory instead of the calling process. I believe it is fixed in 3.2 (I cannot find bug number in gnome bugzilla right now).

As a temporary measure I would advice to use `$PWD` variable:

```
nautilus $PWD/.
```

instead of

```
nautilus .
```

Comment: Pro tip:  you can configure Nautilus to handle the desktop, and therefore will probably will make this behavior work, by enabling "Have file manager handle the desktop" under the Desktop section.

Comment: Note to Googlers and other people who may have stumbled upon this question: the above comment is no longer true. The code in Nautilus allowing it to draw the desktop was completely removed in GNOME 3.8.